# Custom EditForm displays only the Save and Cancel buttons and no columns at all!

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I have created a new EditForm for my document library from SharePoint Designer 2013. Although the code contains all the columns that I need, when I click on the view in browser, I see only 2 Save and 2 Cancel buttons and no columns at all!

[image]
This is the code of this EditForm.aspx which is generated by the SharePoint Designer:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListFormPageTitle runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span class="die">
        <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="LinkTitle" runat="server" id="ID_LinkTitle"/>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='1' height='1' alt="" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div style="padding-left:5px">
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace" id="onetIDListForm">
     <tr>
      <td>
     <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
        <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="Unterlage" ViewFlag="8" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="FALSE" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{900EE069-0B82-48FE-BFE2-D12452ED0A0F}" ListId="900ee069-0b82-48fe-bfe2-d12452ed0a0f" PageType="PAGE_EDITFORM" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" Title="Unterlage" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_f55bf988_c5cd_4519_b45e_744b47fc76b8" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{F55BF988-C5CD-4519-B45E-744B47FC76B8}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><DataSources>
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Unterlage&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True" UseServerDataFormat="True"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="http://coidmo01/sites/powerdoc2" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{900EE069-0B82-48FE-BFE2-D12452ED0A0F}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </SelectParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="http://coidmo01/sites/powerdoc2" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{900EE069-0B82-48FE-BFE2-D12452ED0A0F}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="http://coidmo01/sites/powerdoc2" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{900EE069-0B82-48FE-BFE2-D12452ED0A0F}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </InsertParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="http://coidmo01/sites/powerdoc2" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{900EE069-0B82-48FE-BFE2-D12452ED0A0F}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
</DataSources>
<Xsl>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">ListForm</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
        <div>
            <span id="part1">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </table>
            </span>
            <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator"> </td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton1"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowedit"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-descriptiontext" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Edit" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator"> </td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowedit">
        <xsl:param name="Pos" select="position()"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Title</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>DokumentID</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="pdfDocID" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pdfDocID')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="pdfDocID" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Dokumentnummer.</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="pdDocNumber" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pdDocNumber')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="pdDocNumber" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Dokumentdatum</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="pdDocDate" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pdDocDate')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff4description{$Pos}" FieldName="pdDocDate" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Version.</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff5{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="pdDocVersion" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pdDocVersion')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff5description{$Pos}" FieldName="pdDocVersion" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Aufbewahrungsort</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff6{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="pdDocRepository" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff6',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pdDocRepository')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff6description{$Pos}" FieldName="pdDocRepository" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Status.</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="pdDocStatus" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pdDocStatus')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff7description{$Pos}" FieldName="pdDocStatus" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>ExportPackage</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff8{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="ExportPackage" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff8',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@ExportPackage')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff8description{$Pos}" FieldName="ExportPackage" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>ExportLookup</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="ExportLookup" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@ExportLookup')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="ExportLookup" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Source URL</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff10{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="_SourceUrl" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff10',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@_SourceUrl')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff10description{$Pos}" FieldName="_SourceUrl" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Template Link</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff11{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="TemplateUrl" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff11',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@TemplateUrl')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff11description{$Pos}" FieldName="TemplateUrl" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                            <script>
          var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
          if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
          document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';
        </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="99" class="ms-vb">
                                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   </Xsl>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<ParameterBindings>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="weburl" Location="None" DefaultValue="http://coidmo01/sites/powerdoc2"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{900EE069-0B82-48FE-BFE2-D12452ED0A0F}"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
     </ParameterBindings>
</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>

        </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="FormCustomRedirectControl" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td class="ms-areaseparatorleft"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
    if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorleft'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Are you made any modifications to your custom edit form ? what you need to do in this custom form ?

Comment: No modification yet! I wanted to have a second EditForm with fewer columns. I didn’t have this problem until last week, but this week when I create a new custom edit form with SPD it is like this! The other custom forms which I made earlier have the same problem now too.